# Can't create only widget with kv variable in .py file

Tags: python, kivy

I always see people creating big structures in .kv files. Sometimes they write the kv in a variable in the .py file.

Here I'm trying to create a widget with kv language in .py file but it doesn't work.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextFieldRect

class App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        print("building app")
        self.screen = Screen()
        return self.screen

    def on_start(self):
        print("starting app")
        kv = '''
        MDTextFieldRect:
        '''
        e = Builder.load_string(kv)
        self.screen.add_widget(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.run()
```

And I know that I can do it another way but I want to learn how to do it like this because I have troubles creating some widget with python when it works in kv language.
Here is a working example of how I could do it but I need to learn another way.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextFieldRect

class App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        print("building app")
        self.screen = Screen()
        return self.screen

    def on_start(self):
        print("starting app")
        self.screen.add_widget(MDTextFieldRect())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.run()
```

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work. What is the value of `kv`, if you inspect it does the MDTextFieldRect object appear the same as the one in your working example?

Comment: ```e = Builder.load_string(kv)```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'.
The way I write the kv object seems to not be the good one.

Comment: It sounds like MDTextFieldRect may do something wrong. What happens if you try with just a Label?